# One of the coordinate planes is a tangent plane to the surface $y=x^2 +3z^2$. How can I know which coordinate plane is tangent to it?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

One of the coordinate planes is a tangent plane to the surface  $y=x^2 +3z^2$.

How can I know which coordinate plane is tangent to it?

I was thinking of checking if it was tangent to a point on the 3 coordinate planes and see if it was parallel or intersecting.

Comment: As you see $y\geq0$ and all level curves $c=x^2+3z^2$ are ellipses on $y=c$ plane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that $(x,y,z)=(0,0,0)$ is on the surface and on all three coordinate planes.

Now, in the equation $y = x^2 + 3z^2,$ which is the one variable that *cannot* be negative? Which two coordinate planes does the surface cross through when the other two variables go from positive to negative?

What about the remaining coordinate plane--does the surface stay all on one side of that plane except where it just touches the plane?

This is not a general method for finding tangent planes, but this case just happens to be unusually neat and tidy.

Comment: Yea I ended using that

Answer (score 1):

The surface can be expressed as $y - x^2 - 3z^2 = 0$, and the gradient of $y - x^2 - 3z^2$ will be perpendicular to the surface at $(x,y,z)$. Note that $(-2x,1,-6z)$ is this gradient.

In order for a coordinate hyperplane to be tangent to the surface at $(x,y,z)$, this gradient vector also has to have two entries that are zero. The only way this can happen is if $x = z = 0$, which corresponds to gradient vector $(0,1,0)$. And indeed when $x = z = 0$, one has $y = 0$ and the tangent plane to the surface can be verified through the usual formula to be the coordinate plane $y = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Solve for $z$:
$$3z^2 = y-x^2$$
$$\to f(x,y) = \Big(\frac{y-x^2}{3}\Big)^{1/2}$$
Equations of coordinate planes:
$$\vec v = \vec 0 \text{ where $\vec v = [x,y,z]$}$$
Partial derivatives of $f(x,y)$
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x,y) = -\frac{x}{\sqrt{3(y-x^2)}}$$
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y} f(x,y) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{3(y-x^2)}}$$
Tangent planes given by:
$$-\frac{x}{\sqrt{3(y-x^2)}} = 0$$
$$\to x=0 \text{ provided $y \neq x^2$}$$
$$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3(y-x^2)}} = 0$$
$$\to \emptyset$$
Plug back in $x=0$ to $f(x,y)$:
$$f(0,y) = \sqrt{\frac{y}{3}}$$
Thus, at $z=0$, $y=0$ is tangent to $f(x,y)$.